# calling core methods of jquery validator from custom methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to create a custom validator method but how can I call its core method but getting error, something like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredHidden", function (value, element) {
    if ($(element).is(':visible') == false) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return jQuery.validator.required(value, element);
    }
}, "*");

error: jQuery.validator.required is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredHidden", function (value, element) {
    if ($(element).is(':visible') == false) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return jQuery.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element);
    }
}, "*");
```

See [this](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/15/37923/).